# CommandLine::Application swallows my exceptions in main, how to avoid?

Tags: ruby

Example:

```
require 'commandline'
class App < CommandLine::Application
    def initialize
    end
    def main
        raise 'foo'
    end
end
```

results in

```
$ ruby test.rb
ERROR: foo
```

And here the problem starts: during development there will always be Exceptions thrown deep somewhere in my code and I need to see the stacktrace and not some mangled message.

Thanks to **rampion**, I'm now using this solution:

```
require 'commandline'
class App < CommandLine::Application
    def initialize
    end
    def main
        raise 'foo'
        rescue Exception => e
            puts format_like_real_exception e
    end
    def format_like_real_exception(e)
        s = ''
        b = e.backtrace
        s << b.shift << ': ' << e.message << "\n"
        b.each { |l| s << "\t" << l << "\n" }
        s
    end
end
```

Of course the formatter is not necessary, but I prefer it the way they're originally formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternately, you could just rescue the errors in `main`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'commandline'
class App < CommandLine::Application
    def initialize
    end
    def main
        raise 'foo'
    rescue Exception => e
        puts "BACKTRACE:"
        puts e.backtrace
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found so far:

1. Change `CommandLine::Application` to `CommandLine::Application_wo_AutoRun`
2. rename method `main` to something else which isn't used, e.g `start
3. call static method `App.run` which returns the instance and then call your `start` method on it

Full example:

```
require 'commandline'
class App < CommandLine::Application_wo_AutoRun
    def initialize
    end
    def start
        raise 'foo'
    end
end
app = App.run
app.start
```

The [documentation](http://rubyforge.org/docman/view.php/632/233/posted-docs.index.html) mentions `Application_wo_AutoRun` but doesn't assist how to proceed further. Only source studying helped here.